# How can scene A, who segues to scene B, know when the user has finished with scene B, and scene A is displayed again?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue

this should be pretty simple, but for some reason I can't work it out.

Scene A, does a pushSegue to scene B. Everything works fine, the user clicks back in the navigation item at the top of scene B, and returns to scene A.

How can I have scene A informed about this? (The idea is, the user changes some parameters in scene B, that means scene A has to redraw itself).

I have read a bit about unwind segues, but I don't think that solves my problem, going back already works thanks to I guess the navigation controller mechanism, and the two ways for using unwind segues don't seem useful as I don't have a button to connect the unwind segue way to (just a Navigation Item that contains the Back button at runtime) and I don't need to trigger it programatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A will get `viewDid/WillAppear:` calls when B is popped off the stack. Ideally B will have updated an independent model object so it doesn't have to talk directly to A to let it know.

If you need more specific control, make A the delegate of the navigation controller. It will then get informed about specific push/pop events with the actual view controllers passed as parameters.

You can also pass blocks to B from A before the push, which are to be executed whenever important things are changed, or make A a delegate of B.